# A simpler proof that one dimensional time dependant differential equations have unique solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to read through V. Arnold's book on ordinary differential equations. One of his exercises asks the following question: Prove that a one dimensional differential equation of the form

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = v(x,t) $$

has unique solutions (we don't need to prove existence). After a couple hours I managed to concoct a solution, but maybe I'm thinking around the strategy Arnold intended, missing something that makes the proof much easier.

First, I prove that if $v(x,t) < w(x,t)$ for all $x$ and $t$, and if $v$ has an integral curve $c_0$ and $w$ has an integral curve $c_1$ sharing the initial conditions $(x_0,t_0)$, then $c_0(t) \leq c_1(t)$ for $t \geq t_0$, and $c_0(t) \geq c_1(t)$ for $t \leq t_0$. This is easy enough. Next, I introduce a curve $c$ solving the differential equation $dx/dt = v(x,t)$. Switching to the coordinates $(y,t)$ rather than $(x,t)$, where $y(x,t) = x - c(t)$ reduces the problem to proving that the integral curve through the origin of the differential equation

$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = w(y,t) $$

is unique, where $w(0,t) = 0$ for all real values of $t$. I use Taylor's theorem to strictly upper bound $|w(y,t)|$ for $y \neq 0$ locally around the origin by $A|y| + B|ty|$ for some values $A$ and $B$ (If $w$ is $C^2$, we can use Taylor's theorem, which with an analysis of the integral remainder formula gives the required bounds). If we calculate solutions for this vector field, the inequality theorem we proved allows us to bound any solution which doesn't start at the origin away from the origin, showing that the curve $y(t) = 0$ is a unique solution to the differential equation for any point on the $y$ axis. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $v$ is $C^1$, and $x_1,x_2$ are two solutions with $x_1(0)=x_2(0)$.  Then by the fundamental theorem of calculus, 
\begin{align}
v(x_2(t),t)-v(x_1(t),t)&=\int_{x_1(t)}^{x_2(t)}\frac
{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,t)dx\\
&=(x_2(t)-x_1(t))\int_0^1\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}((1-s)x_1(t)+sx_2(t),t)ds\\
&\equiv(x_2(t)-x_1(t))V(t).
\end{align}
Let $\Delta x(t)=x_2(t)-x_1(t)$.  Then $\Delta x(0)=0$, and $\Delta x(t)$ satisfies the differential equation
\begin{align}
\Delta x'(t)=\Delta x(t)V(t).
\end{align}
This means $\Delta x(t)=\Delta x(0)\exp\int_0^t V(s)ds$, from which the result follows.

Comment: Very nice. Do you even need to assume continuous differentiability, or just the derivative being integrable?

Comment: Integrable is too weak; for example, nonuniqueness fails for $v(x,t)=|x|^{p}$ if $p<1$.  But $p\ge 1$ works, and more generally locally bounded ($v$ locally Lipschitz, see the Picard-Lindelof theorem).